# microtype character code

Tags: luatex, microtype

I am using lualatex `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011062107 (rev 4277)` with microtype `[2011/08/18 v2.5 <beta-07> Micro-typographical refinements (RS)]`. My computer has an american keyboard and I am typesetting in German with TeXShop.

There is a different behavior when I switch the keyboard to German and type an `ö` or when I use the sequence `alt-u` `o`.

I am puzzelled by the fact, that a hex-editor shows `c3` `b6` in both cases. How do I distinguish with a tool such as a hex-editor, but capable of showing the difference. The output pdfs are attached as an example.

[image: example one] [image: example two]

now with the minimal example (microtype):

[image]

no microtype: [image]

Comment: Can you zip a minimal example and upload it somewhere?

Comment: This has quite certainly nothing to do with microtype. Perhaps your code is wrong or your file encoding. Make a small complete example that demonstrates the problem and put the tex-file and the pdf somewhere on the net (at best hidden in a zip-file so that they can be downloaded without change).

Comment: I would like to post a minimal example, but it behaves again differently. I am interested in a tool that does for UTF-8 the same that does my good old hexEdit for ascii. If there is no difference in the input file, there cannot be a difference in the output file (I am sure about that ;)

Comment: I managed to pin it down (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9089117/test.tex.zip) and my world is still okay. The hexeditor shows different character codes. I still do not quite understand how I got the other characters. Did someone notice that copy and paste (on a mac) does some interpretation/ changes? Please note how it seems to work without microtype.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: now with pdfs: (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9089117/all.zip)

Comment: Well the viewer can also be at fault. But if you use sensible fonts the o in ö should never be separated from its points. But without code we can't know what fonts you are using.

Comment: It doesn't work without microtype either. If you copy & paste in the pdf you will see that the umlauts consist of two characters in the first paragraph: "natu.rliche". With microtype this only gets visible. It is possible in unicode to encode an "ö" as "o + combining accent (diaresis)" and that is what you somehow got. It is probably possible to tell luatex to map these combinations to the real "ö"  (e.g. with a feature file), but I would suggest that you simply try to avoid them ;-).

Comment: Not sure how you get the hex editor display both as `c3 b6`. I use Vim and displayed the file in hex mode, the `ü` in the first paragraph is `75 cc 88`, which means `u` + `combining diaeresis`, as @UlrikeFischer already pointed out. While in the second paragraph it is `c3 bc`, which is the utf-8 code for `ü`. By the way, you can use Vim's status line to conveniently see the code point of char under the cursor

Comment: With XeTeX one can say `\XeTeXinputnormalization=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hex-editor to look at the character codes, but you have to look at every one in the paragraph, not only the suspicious ones close to the problem. Please note how the space between `Jahr` and `1950` is affected by the incorrect `ä` in `Tatsächlich` in the first paragraph. The second paragraph has the right `ä`. [image: two paragraphs of text]

Download of the [code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9089117/microtype.zip) example.

Please delete the post, if it is to specific to my particular problem...